# How do I change the color of the text "labels" of the Form elements of a simple component of a React JS application?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, forms, colors

I have a simple React component called "Login.js" that uses forms, and it returns the following:-

```
return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} noValidate className={loading ? 'loading' : ''}>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <Form.Input
          label="Username"
          placeholder="Enter your username..."
          name="username"
          type="text"
          value={values.username}
          error={errors.username ? true : false}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <Form.Input
          label="Password"
          placeholder="Enter your password..."
          name="password"
          type="password"
          value={values.password}
          error={errors.password ? true : false}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <Button type="submit" primary>
          Login
        </Button>
      </Form>
      {Object.keys(errors).length > 0 && (
        <div className="ui error message">
          <ul className="list">
            {Object.values(errors).map((value) => (
              <li key={value}>{value}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

How do I change the colors of the text labels "Username" and "Password"? Do I need to create another CSS file called "Login.css" within the components folder, import that into "Login.js", and make the changes there? If so, how do I do that? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Style variable in the render method and then access it in the JSX

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const usernameStyle = {
      color: "green",
    };
    const passwordStyle = {
      color: "blue",
    };

    return (
      <>
      <Form.Input style={usernameStyle} ... />
      <Form.Input style={passwordStyle} ... />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Else, you can also define style inline, as varaible or via a separate css file.

You can find all the options [here](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use `style={{color: "red"}}` nested within your tag. Like:

```
<Form.Input
          label="Username"
          placeholder="Enter your username..."
          style={{color: "red"}}
/>
```

The website linked below talks about css in react

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, even though there are no errors at all.